# Error : DEP1630 : Invalid "TargetOsVersion" property

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10

**Note**: The github project is [here](https://github.com/wikimedia/apps-win8-wikipedia). I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. If you are able to run the program on your Windows 10 computer then you can help me much easier than those that don't.

I am trying to get a Windows Store App to work.  It's basically the Wikipedia Windows Store App that was designed for Windows 8 to run on Windows 10 for my wiki instead. I took the source from Github created a new project association in the store.  However, I can't actually debug the program yet. I get the following error when i try to run the code:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source
Error       Error : DEP1630 : Invalid "TargetOsVersion" property in the recipe file "C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\bin\x64\Debug\WikipediaMetroTest.build.appxrecipe"    WikipediaMetroTest          IntelliSense
```

I can't seem to figure out where this recipe file is at. Any help?

Here are the contents of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Machine>8-1</Machine>
    <WindowsUser>Paul</WindowsUser>
    <TargetPlatformIdentifier>Windows</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <SolutionConfiguration>Debug|x64</SolutionConfiguration>
    <PackageArchitecture>x64</PackageArchitecture>
    <PackageIdentityName>GamepadUniverse.PadPedia</PackageIdentityName>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\bld\x64\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppXManifest Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\bin\x64\Debug\AppxManifest.xml">
      <PackagePath>AppxManifest.xml</PackagePath>
      <ReRegisterAppIfChanged>true</ReRegisterAppIfChanged>
    </AppXManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\js\jquery.localize.js">
      <PackagePath>js\jquery.localize.js</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\js\l10n-setup.js">
      <PackagePath>js\l10n-setup.js</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\js\mediawiki.js">
      <PackagePath>js\mediawiki.js</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\js\propertiesFileReader.js">
      <PackagePath>js\propertiesFileReader.js</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\js\default.js">
      <PackagePath>js\default.js</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\js\find.js">
      <PackagePath>js\find.js</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\js\jquery-1.7.2.js">
      <PackagePath>js\jquery-1.7.2.js</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\js\share.js">
      <PackagePath>js\share.js</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\js\wikiview.js">
      <PackagePath>js\wikiview.js</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ady-cyrl.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ady-cyrl.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-aeb.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-aeb.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-af.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-af.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ar.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ar.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-arc.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-arc.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-arn.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-arn.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-as.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-as.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ast.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ast.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-avk.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-avk.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ba.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ba.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-bar.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-bar.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-be-tarask.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-be-tarask.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-bg.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-bg.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-bjn.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-bjn.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-bn.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-bn.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-br.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-br.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-bs.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-bs.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ca.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ca.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ckb.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ckb.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-cs.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-cs.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-cv.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-cv.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-cy.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-cy.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-da.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-da.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-de.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-de.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-diq.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-diq.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-dsb.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-dsb.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-el.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-el.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-en.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-en.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-eo.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-eo.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-es-formal.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-es-formal.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-es.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-es.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-et.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-et.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-eu.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-eu.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-fa.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-fa.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-fi.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-fi.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-fo.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-fo.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-fr.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-fr.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-frp.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-frp.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-fur.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-fur.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-gd.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-gd.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-gl.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-gl.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-gu.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-gu.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-he.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-he.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-hi.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-hi.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-hr.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-hr.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-hsb.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-hsb.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-hu.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-hu.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ia.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ia.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-id.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-id.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ilo.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ilo.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-is.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-is.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-it.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-it.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ja.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ja.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ka.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ka.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-khw.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-khw.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-kk-cyrl.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-kk-cyrl.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-km.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-km.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-kn.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-kn.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ko.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ko.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ksh.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ksh.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ky.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ky.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-lad.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-lad.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-lb.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-lb.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-li.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-li.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ln.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ln.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-lt.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-lt.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-lus.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-lus.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-lv.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-lv.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-map-bms.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-map-bms.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-mk.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-mk.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ml.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ml.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-mr.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-mr.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ms.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ms.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-mt.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-mt.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-nds-nl.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-nds-nl.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ne.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ne.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-nl.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-nl.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-nn.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-nn.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-no.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-no.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-or.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-or.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-os.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-os.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-pa.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-pa.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-sl.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-sq.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-sq.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-sr-ec.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-sr-ec.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-sr-el.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-sr-el.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-sv.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-sv.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-sw.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-sw.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-ta.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-ta.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-te.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-te.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-th.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-th.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-zh-hk.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-zh-hk.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\assets\www\messages\messages-zh-tw.properties">
      <PackagePath>messages\messages-zh-tw.properties</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\about.html">
      <PackagePath>about.html</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\default.html">
      <PackagePath>default.html</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\css\target.css">
      <PackagePath>css\target.css</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\css\default.css">
      <PackagePath>css\default.css</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\images\secondary-tile.scale-100.png">
      <PackagePath>images\secondary-tile.scale-100.png</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\images\secondary-tile.scale-140.png">
      <PackagePath>images\secondary-tile.scale-140.png</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\images\secondary-tile.scale-180.png">
      <PackagePath>images\secondary-tile.scale-180.png</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\images\splashscreen.scale-100.png">
      <PackagePath>images\splashscreen.scale-100.png</PackagePath>
      <ReRegisterAppIfChanged>true</ReRegisterAppIfChanged>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\images\splashscreen.scale-140.png">
      <PackagePath>images\splashscreen.scale-140.png</PackagePath>
      <ReRegisterAppIfChanged>true</ReRegisterAppIfChanged>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\images\splashscreen.scale-180.png">
      <PackagePath>images\splashscreen.scale-180.png</PackagePath>
      <ReRegisterAppIfChanged>true</ReRegisterAppIfChanged>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\images\storelogo.png">
      <PackagePath>images\storelogo.png</PackagePath>
      <ReRegisterAppIfChanged>true</ReRegisterAppIfChanged>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\win8-wide-tile.scale-100.png">
      <PackagePath>win8-wide-tile.scale-100.png</PackagePath>
      <ReRegisterAppIfChanged>true</ReRegisterAppIfChanged>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\win8-wide-tile.scale-140.png">
      <PackagePath>win8-wide-tile.scale-140.png</PackagePath>
      <ReRegisterAppIfChanged>true</ReRegisterAppIfChanged>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\win8-wide-tile.scale-180.png">
      <PackagePath>win8-wide-tile.scale-180.png</PackagePath>
      <ReRegisterAppIfChanged>true</ReRegisterAppIfChanged>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\win8-wide-tile.scale-80.png">
      <PackagePath>win8-wide-tile.scale-80.png</PackagePath>
      <ReRegisterAppIfChanged>true</ReRegisterAppIfChanged>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
    <AppxPackagedFile Include="C:\Users\Paul\OneDrive\GITHUB\PadPedia WSA\WikipediaMetro\WikipediaMetroTest\bin\x64\Debug\ReverseMap\resources.pri">
      <PackagePath>resources.pri</PackagePath>
    </AppxPackagedFile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResolvedSDKReference Include="C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.WinJS.2.0\1.0\">
      <Name>Microsoft.WinJS.2.0</Name>
      <Version>1.0.9600.17018</Version>
      <Architecture>Neutral</Architecture>
      <FrameworkIdentity>Name=Microsoft.WinJS.2.0, MinVersion=1.0.9600.17018</FrameworkIdentity>
      <AppxLocation>C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.WinJS.2.0\1.0\Microsoft.WinJS.2.0.appx</AppxLocation>
      <MoreInfo>http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/%3fLinkId=260891</MoreInfo>
    </ResolvedSDKReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Does it have anything to do with the following line?:

```
<TargetPlatformIdentifier>Windows</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
```

Comment: doesn't the second line of the error give the files path?

Comment: @KenTucker I have posted the file above, please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Does it run if you select x86 instead of x64?

Comment: I don't even see a TargetOsVersion property in this file.

Comment: Have you checked your project file(like `WikipediaMetroTest.csproj`)? You can open it with "Notepad" and for a Windows 10 Universal app, it should have elements like following `<TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
   <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
   <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>`. Are your application's properties right?

Comment: Swapped:<TargetPlatformIdentifier>Windows</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion> for your code

Comment: Now i get errorSeverity Code Description Project File Line Source
Warning MSB3783 Project "WikipediaMetroTest" depends upon SDK "Windows Library for JavaScript 2.0 v1.0" which was released originally for apps targeting "UAP 8.1". To verify whether "Windows Library for JavaScript 2.0 v1.0" is compatible with "UAP 10.0.10240.0", contact the SDK author or see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309181. WikipediaMetroTest C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 2048 Build

Comment: And another error:Severity Code Description Project File Line Source
Error APPX1639 File 'Windows.props' not found. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12395&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=PlatformMultiTargeting&o1=UAP&o2=10.0.10240.0 for more information. WikipediaMetroTest C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets 657 Build

Comment: What is the new project you created? A Windows 8.1 app or a UWP app?  I can run the Github project by editing `WikipediaMetroTest.jsproj` with `<VisualStudioVersion>14.0</VisualStudioVersion>`. And if you want to port this project to UWP, you can refer to [Porting a Windows Runtime 8.x project to a UWP project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt188203.aspx).

Comment: @JayZuo That was a super simple fix. Everything works well now!  If you post an answer I'll reward you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move my comment to answer as it works for OP:

The github project you've mentioned is built with Visual Studio 2013, if you want to load it in Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 Community, you can edit its project file and change the `VisualStudioVersion`. You can open `WikipediaMetroTest.jsproj` with "Notepad", find the [`<VisualStudioVersion>` element](https://github.com/wikimedia/apps-win8-wikipedia/blob/master/WikipediaMetro/WikipediaMetroTest/WikipediaMetroTest.jsproj#L50) and change it to `<VisualStudioVersion>14.0</VisualStudioVersion>`. Then you can load and debug the project correctly.